# 1 network daemon or 2 network daemons

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking

If I am implementing a feature such as upload / download on a dual core machine dedicated for this purpose in ruby, is there any way to have a process per core? Is there any point in having one socket open for uploading and one socket open for downloading? If I take this approach, are there any downsides? Is there any way to optimize this, or might I just as well just have one daemon for both upload and download?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like premature optimization to me

Comment: Maybe, but I guess I'd like to make a decision like this in advance.

Comment: Understood, but all the reasons that come to mind for doing it are performance-based. That is, utilizing two CPUs. On the other hand, it seems to me like it would add a *lot* of complexity. So, you're adding complexity for a performance gain you might not even get or need. If you think you might want to do this sometime in the future, just write your code for 1 process, but keep this in mind so it won't be too hard to break it out if/when you need it.